# MPAndroidChart bar chart takes full width if one value is to large

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in one of my projects, i am using horizontal bar charts. Several times if the value of 1 filed it too large the graph kind of shows only that value and rest all other values becomes 0.

Now i understand this is correct behavior since it calculate percentage and divide the values but even in those cases this values should be shown. Is there any way to achieve this ??

Here is what it looks like : 
[image]

Value of all other fields are pretty small less than 2000 !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is clearly visible in the screenshot you provided, the values are shown. **They are just very small** (exactly as small as you set them to be) and therefore they are not drawn any bigger on the chart.

I honestly don't know what you expect?

If you want the bars of the small values to be "bigger", then use bigger values.

Something like a logarithmic scale is not yet available for the axes.

Answer (score 0):

In MP Android chart there is no way to handle this issue of 'one-value-is-too-large'. I faced this issue and had to implement a design change. In my chart most values were of range 10 units and only one value was very large around 4000 units. So I decide to not display the large value in chart and display it below the chart. Here is an image view

[image: Large value is displayed below the dynamic chart]

Comment: Add these lines to your code:

    chartView.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(barData.getYMax() + 20);
    chartView.getAxisRight().setAxisMaxValue(barData.getYMax() + 20);
You can change number 20 in above given code as per your requirements